# customizing multiple author affiliations in Orgmode for latex export using package authblk

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, hyperref

I have this setup in my Orgmode doc and it doesnt export the author affiliations to latex or pdf.
Instead I get a heuristic 'immediate' in place of authors
I have added Latex to Org -babel-Load languages in .emacs 
What must be done to allow babel to evaluate Latex code blocks?
Is there a hyperef setup that I must change?

```
#+Title: Multiple Author affiliations in OrgMode Latex export 
#+date: 11 Feb 2016
#+latex_class: article
#+latex_class_options: [a4paper]
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+OPTIONS: author:nil
#+latex_header: \usepackage{float}
#+latex_header: \usepackage{graphicx}
#+latex_header: \usepackage{authblk} 

    #+BEGIN_LATEX
    \author[1]{Author One}
    \author[1]{Author TwoTwo}
    \author[1]{Author TwoTwoo}
    \author[1,2]{Author TwoTwooo}
    \author[1]{Author Three}
    \author[1]{Author TwoTw}
    \author[1]{Author Four}
    \author[1]{Author Fourrr}
    \author[2]{Author Fourrrr}
    \author[2]{Author Twenty}
    \affil[1]{Guided Therapeutics Centre}
    \affil[2]{Division of theatre}
    #+END_LATEX
```

I get this pdf

[pdfoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipsbn.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this reply today from the org-mode mailing list which had the right solution
On Thursday, 18 Feb 2016 at 10:05, Prakash Nayak wrote:

> I have this setup in my Orgmode doc and it doesn't export the author
> affiliations to latex or pdf.

I've never used authblk but I would imagine that you are expected to
define the authors *before* the \begin{document} line in the generated
LaTeX.  Using a latex block (and, by the way, depending on the version
of org you are using, the syntax for these has changed), you will be
generating LaTeX which will appear *after* the beginning of the
document.

I think you want to put each of the \author and \affil lines in the
header:

```
#+latex_header: \author[1]{Author One}
#+latex_header: \affil[1]{Guided Therapeutics Centre}
```

etc.

Give this a try.